# objective c multipart form file upload with user credentials

Tags: objective-c, node.js, upload, multipartform-data, formidable

I have the following code in objective C that works just fine for uploading a file via POST to node.js /formidable.

I would however like to include user credentials and additional details about the file in this POST request. I have looked all over and could not find an example that would allow me to achieve this.

Please advice what do I need to achieve the objective above.

Here is my code in Objective C:

```
-(void) uploadToServer:(NSData*) mediaData
                         asType:(int) mediaType
                         asFile:(NSString*) saveFileAs{

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"subFolder"   : G_deviceName,
                             @"filename"    : saveFileAs
                             };

    NSString *boundary = [self generateBoundaryString];


        // configure the request

    NSString * urlForUploading = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/upload",G_appServerURL ];

    NSURL *uploadToURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlForUploading];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:uploadToURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        // set content type

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        // create body

    NSData *httpBody = [self createBodyWithBoundary:boundary parameters:params mediaData:mediaData fieldName:@"fieldName"];

    self.session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];  // use sharedSession or create your own

    NSURLSessionTask *task = [self.session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:httpBody completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"activeUpload" object:nil userInfo:nil];
            return;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"uploadToServer successful." );

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"activeUpload" object:nil userInfo:nil];
        }

        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"result = %@", result);
    }];
    [task resume];

}

- (NSData *)createBodyWithBoundary:(NSString *)boundary
                        parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                         mediaData:(NSData*)mediaData
                         fieldName:(NSString *)fieldName
{
    NSMutableData *httpBody = [NSMutableData data];

        // add params (all params are strings)

    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *parameterKey, NSString *parameterValue, BOOL *stop) {
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", parameterKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", parameterValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }];

        // add image data

    NSString *formName = [parameters objectForKey:@"subFolder"];
    NSString *filename  = [parameters objectForKey:@"filename"];
    NSString *mimetype  = @"image/jpeg";  //[self mimeTypeForPath:path];

    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", formName, filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", mimetype] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:mediaData];
    [httpBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    return httpBody;
}

- (NSString *)generateBoundaryString
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

}
```

Here is the code in node.js Server that receives this POST request and saves the file:

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){

```
  var subFolder;

  // create an incoming form object
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.multiples = false;

  form.uploadDir = '/home/uploads'

  form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file) {

    console.log('entered fileBegin ... ');
      form.uploadDir = form.uploadDir + name;

  });

  // every time a file has been uploaded successfully, rename it to it's orignal name
  form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));

  });


    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        if (err) 
          console.log("In form.parse, error occured : " + util.inspect(err));

        console.log("parsing form now...");

    });

  // log any errors that occur
  form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
  });

  // once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client
  form.on('end', function() {
        console.log('File uploaded to location : ' + form.uploadDir);
    res.end('success');
  });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess form.parse provides those extra params

```
 form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
   console.log("parsing form now..."+ JSON.stringify(fields));
 });
```

In case you still want earlier then  check this

```
 form.on('field', function(name, value) { });
```

and in case that also comes late then **try re-ordering** the sequence from HTML form

Comment: form.parse does provide access to the fields, but the problem is for some reason form.parse gets executed after the file upload has completed. Here is the sequence in which these methods get executed: 
"upload request received", "entered file begin", "form.on" 'file'  and then  form.parse.

i need access to fields before I start uploading so I can authenticate the user.

Comment: I'm already doing that, rename at that time works fine. The thing is if the user is not authorized then why should an upload even go through and take up server resources.

Comment: did you tried form.on('field', function(name, value) {
});      and in case that also hosts late then  try re-ordering the sequence from HTML form

Comment: Thank you ! that worked very well. form.on('field', function(name,value){ }); does get called before file begin. I will accept this answer, it does exactly what I need.